# Новичок против адаптивной верстки

Tags: html, css

Я совсем новичок, верстаю два с половиной месяца, сверстал свой первый лендинг и когда пришел час делать шаг навстречу адаптиву столкнулся с страшной проблемой(  При сжатии страницы до 320пикс. вся моя верстка прижимается к левому краю, и в силу того, что я совсем тугой еще, я не знаю почему оно прижимается к левому краю, пожалуйста, объясните мне, шо оно такое, добрые люди

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #353B3E;
    padding: 15px;
}
.wrapper{
    max-width: 1660px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
.header__content{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}

.header__name{
    color: #BBD5D9;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    line-height: 1;
}

.header_links{
    width: 100%;
    
}

.ul_header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style-type: none;
    
    
}
.a_header{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F7F8F8;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: relative;
}
.a_header:after{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #F7F8F8;
    content: "";
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}
.a_header:hover:after{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header__content">
            <img src="./logo.svg" alt="photo">
            <div class="header__name">
                ооо "техносервис промгрупп"
            </div>
            <div class="header_links">
                <ul class="ul_header">
                    <li class="li_header"><a class="a_header"   href="#">Фильтрующие материалы</a></li>
                    <li class="li_header"><a class="a_header" href="#">Услуги по очистке воды</a></li>
                    <li class="li_header"><a class="a_header" href="#">О компании</a></li>
                    <li class="li_header"><a class="a_header" href="#">Телефон</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а стили того блока, который выпирает, покажи )

Comment: .ul_main{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.li_main{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #353b3e;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 195px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.li_main:hover{
    background-color: #b3d4fc;
    transition: 0.9s;
}

.a_main{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    
    color: grey;
}

Comment: нифига так не понятно ) Попробуй временно убрать то, что выпирает - будет л результат

Comment: неа, вообще ничего не изменилось( слушай, а из-за того что у меня горизонтальный скрол имеется  может быть этот скрол влияет ?

Comment: Добавьте, если нет, `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` и настройте его. Если не до конца поможет, используйте css медиа-запросы

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот некоторые подсказки которые вам помогут найти баги в верстке:

**1) Использование онлайн валидаторов HTML CSS, в которые вы вбиваете ваш код и система автоматически анализирует его и указывает на ошибки.**

Примеры сайтов: [www.freeformatter.com](https://freeformatter.com)

https://validator.w3.org

На самом деле их сотни, в поисковике найдете тот, который максимально удобен для вас.

**2) При анализе как выглядит ваша верстка на разных устройствах, используйте также специализированные сервисы для этого.**

Простое изменение размера окна браузера на 100% вас подведет и не покажет реальной картины, так было у меня при отображении верстки на Iphone и других Ios устройствах.

Сайт: [www.mobiletest.me](http://www.mobiletest.me)   на этом сайте реально происходит эмуляция устройств, а не как в остальных сервисах, псевдо-смена разрешений.

**3) Откройте вашу страницу в обычном браузере, нажмите правой кнопкой мыши и выберите "Просмотреть код" или "Инспектировать элемент"**

У вас откроется справа окно разработчика, в режиме онлайн. Там нажимайте на DIV классы (class) или id которые у вас криво отображаются и вам откроется CSS строка кода которая за это отвечает.  Таким образом вы можете убирать какие-то пункты прямо в браузере друг за другом и смотреть что было сделано не так. Это увеличит скорость поиска ошибки. Такой подход будет сразу вам показывать где вы пропустили пункты, более того большинство браузеров показывают сами сразу где и каких пунктов не хватает в CSS.

**4) По вашему вопросу, разрешения экранов нужно прописывать в СSS по типу медиа запросов.**
Вот сайт с подробным описанием [www.htmlbook.ru/css/value/media](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media)

**5) Если вы уже поставили max-width то не забудьте поставить и min-width** при котором верстка дальше не будет лезть в экраны размером менее 300 например и появится скролл вправо.

**6) Также поэкспериментируйте с разными средами разработки.** Писать код в обычном текстовом блокноте - это уровень про, но если вы новичок используйте для начала более продвинутые средства разработки наподобие PHP Storm, Code LObster и десятки других где вам сразу показываются ошибки.

Comment: Вау, спасибо Вам огромное)))

Comment: я с помощью инспектора как вы и говорили нашел где у меня выпирал блок и все расширилось на максимально доступную ширину))